# Formula in spreadsheet that counts accrued holiday based on the existing adjacent values (or lack of)

Tags: datetime, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm working on a spreadsheet for managing employee attendance, leave and accrued holiday (see below screenshot). I am extending this from a template that I found online.

[image: Attendance, leave and holiday management]

See the active cell NL8, here I want to come up with a formula that totals up accrued holiday based on the days that the employee has worked.

What there is currently is basically the same as 'Leave Days (Month)' and counting any values (leave days) that there is against this employee.

As the entire year is set up in this spreadsheet, the other formulas are like so:

```
=ArrayFormula(SUMPRODUCT((OFFSET($A7,0,31*($A$3-1)+1,1,31)<>"")*(IF(OFFSET($A7,0,31*($A$3-1)+1,1,31)=$NZ$15,0.5,IF(OFFSET($A7,0,31*($A$3-1)+1,1,31)=$NZ$16,0.5,1))*(OFFSET($A$4,0,31*($A$3-1)+1,1,31)))))
```

(just to give you an example of how they are offsetting for each month)

The holiday is accrued at a rate of 2.33 days per calendar month. I need to total this up in the Holiday Accrued column but ideally without having to mark each attended day in a cell for each employee. Is there a way this can be done by only calculating 2.33 per month since a start date to current date for example?

## Edit

If it helps, [here is a read-only copy of my sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZpwylgGJWJ8UKSZTWcm1O2MeZ_9JNEVvKBhzsatV04Q/edit?usp=sharing) that you can make a copy of.

Comment: Sure, here you go - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZpwylgGJWJ8UKSZTWcm1O2MeZ_9JNEVvKBhzsatV04Q/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: can you also add example of desired output? from question itself its not clear what exactly are you after

Comment: If an employee started their job on 28th May, then work out accrued holiday at a rate of 2.33 days per calendar month from that date but only up until present date (I think maybe using 'today' function). So for example, it would be approximately 1.61. To be honest, if there is a better way of calculating this then ideal, I just need to be able to let employees know how many days holiday they can take based on what they've accrued but it would be ideal to have everything all in one spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, you will need to set/get a starting point for each employee. so let's say employee 1  starts at **2/4/2019** (cell **`A15`**):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTA(UNIQUE(TEXT(TO_DATE(ROW(INDIRECT(
 "A"&DATEVALUE(A15)&":A"&DATEVALUE(TODAY())))), "MM-yyyy")))-1)*2.33-
 (DAYS(A15, DATE(YEAR(A15), MONTH(A15), 1))/DAY(EOMONTH(A15, 0))*100%)*2.33+
 (DAYS(TODAY(), DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY()), 1))/(DAY(EOMONTH(TODAY(), 0))-1)*100%)*2.33
```

the formula consists of 3 parts... first part counts days then it converts it into months, counts unique months and multiplies it by 2.33 as requested

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTA(UNIQUE(TEXT(TO_DATE(ROW(INDIRECT(
 "A"&DATEVALUE(A15)&":A"&DATEVALUE(TODAY())))), "MM-yyyy")))-1)*2.33
```

the second part introduces a correction for the case when an employee does not start from the first day of the month

```
=(DAYS(A15, DATE(YEAR(A15), MONTH(A15), 1))/DAY(EOMONTH(A15, 0))*100%)*2.33
```

and the 3rd part compensates days from today's date till the end of this month

```
=(DAYS(TODAY(), DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY()), 1))/(DAY(EOMONTH(TODAY(), 0))-1)*100%)*2.33
```

[image: 0]